# Structure within a Class

Tags: c++, class, structure

I have a class with a structure under private. 
How do I access the data members of that structure?

```
  class ClassStruct
  {
  private:
     struct Struct
     {
        std::string time;
        int temp;
     };
  public:
     ClassStruct();
  };
```

Here is what I tried:

```
struct Struct o;
ClassStruct object;
cout << "Enter time (hh:mm): ";
cin >> object.o.time;
```

But it shows an error on "o".

Comment: "I tried to declare a variable of structure but I guess that's wrong" - nope, that's correct. Show us.

Comment: Struct object; object.temp; this shows an error...

Comment: @hakuna12: So what's the error? Is the declaration in a member or friend of `ClassStruct`? If not, then you can't access the `Struct` name, since it's private.

Comment: struct Struct o;
 ClassStruct object;
 cout << "Enter time (hh:mm): ";
 cin >> object.o.time; 
i tried this. but it shows an error on "o"

Comment: @hakuna12 important tip when asking for help: When you say you got "an error", give the details. Error messages are very precise and technical and they reveal the problem.

Comment: And post a minimal test case with which the error can be reproduced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only access this struct from within the declaring class implementation. In your example the only place you can access it is in the constructor for `ClassStruct`.

**EDIT** to try and explain what people are asking you:

In ClassStruct.h:

```
class ClassStruct
{
private:
   struct Struct
   {
      std::string time;
      int temp;
   };
public:
   ClassStruct();
   void test(){
     Struct good; // This will work.
     good.temp = 5;
   }
};
```

In ClassStruct.cpp

```
ClassStruct::ClassStruct(){
   Struct alsoGood;
   std::cout << "Also Good Here" << std::endl;
}

void nonClassFunction(){
  ClassStruct::Struct bad; // compiler error
}
```

In AnyOther.cpp

```
void wontWork(){
  ClassStruct::Struct alsoBad; // compiler error.
}
```

Comment: And see Vlad's answer below on creating a field of your struct.

Answer (score 2):

To access data members of the structure you need to define an object of this structure. You can define an object of this structure as a data member of the enclosing class or as an object created in methods of the class.

For example

```
  class ClassStruct
  {
  private:
     struct Struct
     {
        std::string time;
        int temp;
     } obj1;
  public:
     ClassStruct();
     void SomeMethod()
     {
        Struct obj2;
        // some operations with obj2
     }

  };
```